# Sync another remote in Git

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repository **A** and created local branches for all remote tracking branches. Next I have added another remote **B** and pushed all the branches from **A** to **B** using:

```
git push other --all
```

A couple days later I pulled from **A**:

```
git pull origin
```

and got a bunch of new changes. Now I want to update the remote **B** with those changes so I have tried:

```
git push other --all
```

but then it just says:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Do I need to explicitly push the changes to **B** on those branches that was updated after the first push to **B**?

Or is there some simpler way to update **B** with any changes fetched from **A**?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `git pull origin` with no branch name specified, Git will first fetch the commits for *all* your remote tracking branches, then it will attempt to merge the new commits into the *current* branch on which you are working (`master` by default).

One explanation for what you are seeing is that the current branch on which you are working did not receive any new commits during the fetch.  The other branches also would not have gotten updated.  Then when you did `git push other --all`, Git told you that repository B was already up to date.

To remedy the situation, you need to make sure that all the local branches get updated.  Then `git push other --all` should reflect the changes from the remote A.